# Error with an Observable in model with Angular dynamic component loading

Tags: angular

I have a dynamic component that I've been using for a while. Now I want to add an "Observable" into its model so that I can trigger a change from outside the component. So I have a service (external to the component) that has:

```
  public menuToggleSubject = new Subject<any>();
  public menuToggleSubjectTrigger: Observable<any> = this.menuToggleSubject.asObservable();

  public toggleMenu() {
    this.menuToggleSubject.next();
  }
```

In my model for the component I have:

```
export class LayoutHeader {
    constructor(public sideNavToggleSubjectTrigger: Observable<any>
    ) {}
```

Then, in the component where I'm loading the dynamic component, I have:

```
this.item = { sideNavToggleSubjectTrigger: this.siteService.menuToggleSubjectTrigger };
```

However, I get the following error:

> error TS2322: Type '{ (**removed**): ({ component: typeof (**removed**) is
>   not assignable to type 'LayoutHeader'. Types of property
>   'sideNavToggleSubjectTrigger' are incompatible.    Type
>   'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable'. Two
>   different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated. Property
>   'source' is protected in type 'Observable' but public in type
>   'Observable'.

Note: I did remove some text above that was not relevant (as I removed other members of my LayoutHeader class for clarity). I think the main error/problem is that the two definitions of Observable do not match. But I don't know why.

Comment: Check the imports for observable.

Comment: @cgTag - I did. In both cases they are: import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable"; However, it may be that my dynamically loaded components has "^5.5.8" for rxjs and the main project has "5.5.6". I'll try making them the same.

Answer (score 0):

I was right in my response to cgTag that the rxjs in the dynamically loaded component and the host for that component need to be the same version. Once I updated both package.json's to the same version all was well. I was right, but I don't like it :) as this creates a pretty fragile link. If anyone knows a way around this, please let me know. [I plan on asking a separate SO question for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51029775/dependency-version-mismatch-between-dynamically-loaded-component-and-its-host)